# How to send SQL query from JSP to servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, encoding

I have created a JSP page that sends the custom SQL query to the servlet to fetch records from the database. But the original query has been modified when I send the query with LIKE operator.

I have applied `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` but it will not work.

Original query: `select * from table where coloum_name like '%AF%';`

To get the query in servlet I have used `String SQL = request.getParameter("SQL") == null ? "" : request.getParameter("SQL");`

But here I have  get the modified query: `select * from table where coloum_name like '%';`
[image]

Comment: Do not execute queries you directly get from an user Interface.

Comment: how can I get it?

Comment: Also % is a Special character in URL you have to escape it: http://www.natalihr.nl/html/encoding.html

Comment: What if i enter query "Drop TABLE table"?

Comment: it will work perfectly if I removed the F from the query like select * from table where coloum_name like '%A%';

Comment: Have you ever heard of SQL Injection? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. @Jens is right, you have to encode/decode the query string or you should use the POST-Method.

Comment: @keuleJ POST and encode/decode does not prevent SQL injection

Comment: @Abhinav Have you seen the table i have linked? `%AF` is decoded to `&macr;` it always happen if you have % with two characters

Comment: @Jens you're right, of course. I just thought that's the reasen it doesn't work.

Comment: @Abhinav you have to encode/replace `%` with `%25`

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thnaks